# How to whiten teeth temporarily?

Tags: health

Suppose you have yellowish teeth.
If you were to do a video or photoshoot and wanted to have a white smile, how would you go about whitening your teeth temporarily for the duration of a few hours to a few days?

Comment: Don't you want to visit the dentist?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to whiten or lighten teeth for a video or photo shoot is to have the visual SFX people whiten them for you in post-production with After Effects, Mocca, or other software.

After that, the make-up department technicians know what will pass for on-camera use.

Your own dentist can recommend a procedure to use.

A pharmacy or department store with a cosmetics department typically have several "solutions" made to whiten and brighten teeth and dentures so that they match under different lighting. This is called a metameric match which is hard to achieve non-professionally.

Some think that a "California Smile" looks fake and artificial on older people.

Good luck. Have a good shoot! Break a leg!

Answer (score -1):

@Stan provided a to-the-point answer. I want to add something extra.

Most teeth-whitening techniques use some chemicals, which have a VERY NASTY side effect: they destroy the structure of the teeth. Sometimes, only a few whitenings are enough to have the teeth completely destroyed, i.e. the material actually missing.

Example: H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> (hydrogen peroxide) will whiten your teeth magically. Except that after a few whitenings, the teeth will just break and "disappear".

A former colleague told us the story of his **village**. People heard the trick with the hydrogen peroxide - and used it massively. In less than  one year, (almost) nobody in the village had teeth any more.

---

So the healthiest way to do that is to have the photo / video processed with some filter, either from the beginning (using the camera capabilities), or using some computer software on the photo.

Comment: This answer appears to exaggerate the risk.  See https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326148.php for a discussion of the safety of hydrogen peroxide on the teeth.

Comment: @Tharpa: my answer merely _underlines_ the risk. There are many factors to consider when assessing if the procedure is safe or not. From the article you quoted: `Hydrogen peroxide can cause damage to the enamel of the teeth if a person uses the solution incorrectly.`. Also: `Products containing peroxides, such as hydrogen peroxide and carbamide peroxide, act as bleaching agents` - and it is known that bleaching has the habit to reduce the lifetime of the bleached clothes. Also: `...cracks in the teeth can allow the peroxide to penetrate further into the tooth. This can become a problem...`